# externalize pgfplots, and only pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, chemmacros

I would like to externalize the plots in my document (using `pgplots`), but not other inline stuff, such as bonds automatically drawn by `chemmacros`. That is, in the following test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\ch{A-B}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={\ch{A-B}},
   xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
   ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
]
%  \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to externalize the `tikzpicture` environment, but not the `\ch` command (neither do I want the `\ch` command inside the environment to be recursively externalized, if that can happen).

I could use `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` to switch off and on externalization when needed, but is there a better more automatic way to, for instance, prevent externalization of `\ch`?

*PS*. There is some unwanted interaction between `pgplots` and `chemmacros`. The above example gives wrong results if the `\addplot` is uncommented, or if the x and y limits are commented out. It does not happen if `\ch` is not used inside the plot. This, however, is not immediately related to the question, and might be worth a new one.

Comment: Does the `\ch{A-B}` macro work properly for you in the axis label? For me, the `A` and `B` are positioned too far apart, and the connecting line is diagonal instead of horizontal (regardless of whether the `external` library is used or not).

Comment: @jake Hmm... you're right, it doesn't work here. But it works fine in my working document, so there must be some other option affecting it. I'll investigate tomorrow and modify the example accordingly. Anyway, it should not matter for the main question.

Comment: Hmm, the plot is correct if the formula does not contain a bond (which is a tikzpicture itself)...

Comment: Workaround: put the formula in a savbox and use the savebox for the `xlabel`

Comment: Not a 'complete' answer, but would something like `\RenewDocumentCommand  { \ch } { O{} m }
  {
    \tikzexternaldisable
    \chemformula_ch:nn {#1} {#2}
    \tikzexternalenable
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff` help at all?

Comment: @cgnieder I wonder if externalization should be 'always off' for `\ch` and similar. It's very unlikely to be required for these cases.

Comment: @JosephWright I wondered about that, too. However, adding `\tikzexternaldisable` seems to cause more troubles here... the real problem for this question seems to be another one, anyway: the coordinate systems of the tiktpictures of `\ch` and of the `axis` are interfering. Adding the `disabledatascaling` option to the `axis` seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [@JosephWright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118467/externalize-pgfplots-and-only-pgfplots#comment289994_118467) and [@percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128849/5049) version 4.1 of `chemformula` (the package that provides `\ch` and is loaded by `chemmacros`) can be used in the `axis` environment and also in combination with externalization.

The following needs version 4.1 of `chemformula` (which already made it into TeX Live 2013). It provides the new option `chemformula/tikz-external-disable=true|false` (with `true` as default setting) that disables the externalization of the bonds and arrows (which are drawn with TikZ) by locally adding `\tikzexternaldisable` at the appropriate places.

However, if `\ch` is used inside a `tikzpicture` that *is* to be externalized this feature temporarily needs to be switched off. The following code

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}[2013/08/24]
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\ch{A-B}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setchemformula{tikz-external-disable=false}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={\ch{A-B -> A+ + B-}},
    ]
    \addplot {x*x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

creates only one external file for the `tikzpicture` but none for the bond in `\ch{A-B}` called outside of the `tikzpicture`. The result also looks as it should:

[image]