# tikzpictures inside pgfplots' axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When having a `tikzpicture` inside `pgfplots`'s `axis` environment strange effects can be observed which I guess stem from the fact that the corresponding coordinate systems are interfering with each other:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

My first idea was to add `pgfplots`' option `disabledatascaling` which however seems to make things worse:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   disabledatascaling,
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

What actually does seem to work is adding explicit values for `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
   xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
   ymin =  0, ymax = 25,
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, this still isn't ideal since it forces me to a) set those values explicitly and b) looses the margin between plot and axes. So my question is: is there a better way to deal with situations like this?

Of course this isn't a real world example but the inner `tikzpicture` may actually be drawn by another command (and not look like an arrow at all).

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   disabledatascaling,
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0); B},
   xmin = -6, xmax = 6,
   ymin =  0, ymax = 25,
]
 \addplot {x*x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `xlabel={$A \to B$}`?  Or, am I misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @kmacinnis the tikzpicture in the question just serves as an arbitrary example. I don't actually want to add `A`, `B` or an arrow

Comment: Should that be `\bigskip`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, typo! That's what happens if you modify your example after having inserted the code here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really fun to see the following behavior to get a hold of the mystery

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1cm,0);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1ex,0);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--(1cm,0);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--(1em,0);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--(1ex,0);
           B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What? So we have a suspicion that relative positioning vectors and the dimensions are acting weird. The regular dimensions have no problem. This looks like the same problem Gonzalo Medina discovered and tamed by Jake in [pgfplots: problem in the legend using custom marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125451/pgfplots-problem-in-the-legend-using-custom-marks) .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xlabel={A \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1cm,0pt);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1em,0pt);
             \tikz[show background rectangle]\draw[->](0,0)--++(1ex,0pt);
           B},
]
 \addplot {x*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is (I guess) using nondimensional units as Jake found out in the linked question. Then whoever is in charge of PGF pen syntax at that instant interprets with its own coordinate system. In Gonzalo's case it is kind of visible to see the problem but here it seems that relative syntax is causing something along the lines of `(0,1)++(-1,0)`.

The plausible issue here is that nondimensional coordinates are sent to `\pgf@process` and the coordinate is interpreted by the current coordinate system. When we add the units, the coordinates are not multiplied by the current unit vectors `x,y` and the result is as expected.

As usual, citing Andrew Stacey, nesting TikZ pictures are not a good idea :)

Comment: This is very enlightening, thanks! I agree that nesting tikzpictures is not a good idea. Sometimes it is hard to avoid, though. The question that triggered my question ( http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118467/5049) is an example

Comment: @cgnieder Ouch! I'm afraid that needs a complete analysis. Let's see. I'll try to read the code of `chemmacros` first. Here we go....

Comment: your answer put me on the right track: there are several of those `0`s without unit. I changed them all into `0pt` which solved the visual problems :) Once I've updated to CTAN I'm able to answer the linked question

Comment: @cgnieder I'm more concerned about the externalisation problem. But as you have the total command of the package, I am happy that it is at least partially resolved.

Comment: I have a solution for the externalization problem (or rather a workaround, at least in parts) but it needs my yet unpublished development version...