# chemformula radical in pgfplots title

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, chemformula

I want to typeset a radical in a pgfplots title using chemmacros or more specifically chemformula. However, chemformula uses tikz to typeset radicals and the pgfplot interferes with the coordinates so the radical appears in the wrong position. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title=\ch{H^{.}}]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following picture.

[image: Plot with wrong radical symbol]

The radical symbol is misplaced and the correct position is as follows (cropped a bit too much, but you get the idea).

[image: Formula with correct radical symbol]

Here is [an excerpt from the chemformula source code](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemformula/blob/master/chemformula.sty#L611) which typesets the radical symbol. I guess it needs some keyword to reset the coordinate system in a sense...

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemformula_radical:
  {
    \hbox_overlap_right:n
      {
        \chemformula_tikz:xn
          {
            \l__chemformula_radical_style_tl ,
            baseline ,
            minimum~ height = 0pt ,
            minimum~ width = 0pt ,
            inner~ sep = 0pt ,
            outer~ sep = 0pt ,
            overlay
          }
          {
            \fill (0,0)
              ++(
                \l__chemformula_radical_hshift_dim ,
                \l__chemformula_radical_vshift_dim
              )
              circle (\l__chemformula_radical_radius_dim) ;
          }
      }
    \chemformula_skip_nobreak:N \l__chemformula_radical_space_dim
  }
```

How can I get correct positioning by either modifying the chemformula source or by patching the macro?

Comment: This is actually the same problem as here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128792 and in the end a bug in `chemformula`.

Comment: `(0,0)` should be `(0pt,0pt)`. I fixed it in `chemformula`, the update will soon be sent to CTAN

Comment: @cgnieder I doubt that there is a way to safely nest `tikzpicture`s. You may be able to cure the symptoms here and there, but there will always be cases in which it does not work. Nesting `tikzpicture`s is not supported by the maintainers of Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @Schrödingerscat I know. Nonetheless should `chemformula` (i.e., me) do the most it can in order to avoid problems.

Comment: @cgnieder In order to reduce (or even eliminate) the risk of inheriting unwanted key values you could do simple things like circles with plain pgf (and, as you suggest, with plain, explicit dimensions). I know, it is a lot of efforts, but this is (to the best of my knowledge) how `tcolorbox` manages to be rather immune to the problem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat once it is stable enough `chemformula` will switch to l3draw anyway :)

Comment: @cgnieder I really hope the l3 stuff will be mature, stable and accessible one day.... I wish even more that one day an alternative pops up which is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3):

You should just not nest `tikzpicture`s. Use a `\savebox` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}%<- recommended
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\newsavebox\mytitle
\begin{document}
\savebox\mytitle{\ch{H^{.}}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title=\usebox\mytitle]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nifty solution!

Comment: Although this circumvents my problem, I will not accept the answer since I explicitly stated that I wanted a modification to the chemformula source or patching the macro. @cgnieder provided what I consider the correct answer in the comments.

Comment: @slo This is your choice. However, there is no safe way to nest `tikzpicture`s.