# Tikz External vs. Overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, external

While designing a title page in TikZ I noticed a somewhat unwanted behaviour. When I use the externalize and the `overlay` option for a `tikzpicture` the output is just empty.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (1,1) {test2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Removing the two lines `\usetikzlibrary{external}`, `tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]` gives the wanted behaviour. This is not critical since I can just specify, that this particular image (the title page) should not be externalized, but I think this is somehow unwanted, at least not expected. Is there a proper workaround?

Comment: I recommend just not using externalisation in these cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with how many times you need to compile. Removing `remember picture` does not help. Even if you force Ti*k*Z to remake pictures by `/tikz/external/remake next`  and compile a thousand times it will still show nothing.

The true problem is that when an externalized picture is included back to the original document, <del>`\includegraphics`</del> <del>`\pgfimage`</del> pdfTeX will clip it by its bounding box.

Since pictures with `overlay` has a bounding box of size zero, <del>**everything** will be clipped</del>. (See the next section)

To prove this, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \draw circle(5);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path(-4,-4)(4,4);
}

%\includegraphics{\jobname-figure0.pdf}

\end{document}
```

It will gives you the clipped circle, which is exactly the same as if you open `\jobname-figure0.pdf` in any pdf reader.

[image]

## A more interesting example

Removing `\path(-4,-4)(4,4);`, you will get

[image]

This seems to contradict my theory: without `(-4,-4)` and `(4,4)` the bounding box should be of size zero. But guess what: if you open `\jobname-figure0.pdf` you will see exactly the same arc.

## diving into PDF

- While `\jobname-figure0.pdf` is generated, it has a `/MediaBox` entry, which is rouphly the size of the page.

  - If, in Ti*k*Z, `\pgfresetboundingbox` or `[overlay]` is used, a default value of `[0 0 144 144]` is used. Here `144` means 2 inches. This number comes from nowhere.
  - If the bounding is set explicitly as, say, `\path(-1in,-1in)(2in,2in);` then it is `[0 0 216 216]`. Here `216` means 3 inches.
- While pdfTeX includes the external image in the main file, it

  > takes the BoundingBox of a pdf file from its `/CropBox` if available, otherwise from its `/MediaBox`.

  - For `\pgfresetboundingbox` and `[overlay]`: the `/BBox` entry is `[0 0 144 144]` .
  - For `\path(-1in,-1in)(2in,2in);`: the `/BBox` entry is `[0 0 216 216]` .
- When PDF renderer renders the file, it

  > clips according to the form dictionary’s `/BBox`

  - For `\pgfresetboundingbox` and `[overlay]`, **everything outside** `(0,0) rectangle (2in,-2in)` will be clipped . There is a negetive because the y-axis points down in PDF.

    - To prove this, try to replace `\node at (1,1) {test2};` by ±1.
  - For `\path(-1in,-1in)(2in,2in);`: it is clipped with respect to the that rectangle.

## Possible workaround?

There might be a way to tell pdfTeX not to set the `/Bbox` entry. This is quite hopeless.

The other possibility is to rewrite Ti*k*Z externalizing library so that it will produce an external image with its native bounding box. But keep the information of user-specified bounding box and use it as the image is included back.

(This could be really hard. For exmple if `\tikzmark` is used, what the native bounding box should be? )

For now, a easy workaround is not to export the image

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{external/export next=false}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw(0,0)--(current page.center);
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right about the clipping, but I'm not sure it is `\includegraphics` doing the clipping.

Comment: `overlay` doesn't seem to set the bounding box to zero. If I try `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \node [circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=50mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}`, I don't get nothing. Instead, I get an improperly centred circle - or, rather, I get the south-west quadrant of the circle as you do with your example.

Comment: @cfr I fixed my statement. Please see the update. I hope that the only remaining question is the origin of `144`.

Comment: You still say it is clipped when `\includegraphics` is used to bring it back into the document, but the external image is already clipped when `\includegraphics` has no involvement. Is the point that the viewer clips the PDF in the same way?

Comment: How do you know 144 is 2" and 216 is 3"? Have you tried this with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @cfr Well, my point is, there was a **hope** that `\includegraphics` can bring back the invisible part of an external PDF file. This hope comes from the fact that when I was using image editing programs, I can see the part that exceeds the canvas. (And after all it is not `\includegraphics` because PGF uses its own `\pgfimage` instead.)

Comment: Purely guess. I guess PDF use PostScript Point, and 2 inches is 5.08 cm, which is the radius of our circles. I tried just pdfTeX because I need `\pdfcompresslevel` etc.

Comment: Well, mine was 25mm, but fair enough. XeLaTeX is interesting, though ;).